# Changing argument value using function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, arguments

It looks like I can only change the value of mutable variables using a function, but is it possible to change immutable

#### Code

```
def f(a, b):
    a += 1
    b.append('hi')

x = 1
y = ['hello']
f(x, y)
print(x, y) #x didn't change, but y did
```

#### Result

```
1 [10, 1]
```

So, my question is that is it possible to modify immutable variables using functions? If no then why? What's the reason that python bans people from doing that?

Comment: If you could mutate (change) the values, then they wouldn't be immutable.  It's kind of like asking which flightless birds can fly.  You can return a new value that the caller can then bind to the same name, but that's not the same as changing the value itself, as you can with mutable types.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Does it mean that I have to turn everything into a mutable variable before I modify them in a function?

Answer (score 1):

In python, the list is passed by **object-reference**. Actually, everything in python is an object but when you pass a single variable to function it creates a local copy of that if a value is changed but in case of a list if it creates a local copy even than the reference remains to the previous list object. Hence the value of the list will not get changed.\

You can refer to the [link](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

You can check the following example for clarification.

```
def fun1(b):
    for i in range(0,len(b)):
        b[i]+=4

arr=[1,2,3,4]
print("Before Passing",arr)
fun2(arr)
print("After Passing",arr)

#output
#Before Passing [1, 2, 3, 4]
#After Passing [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you do not want any function to change value accidentally you can use an immutable object such as a tuple.

**Edit:** (Copy example)

We can check it by printing the id of both objects.

```
def fun(a):
    a=5
    print(hex(id(a)))

a=3
print(hex(id(a)))
fun(a)

# Output:
# 0x555eb8890cc0
# 0x555eb8890d00
```

But if we do it with a **List** object:

```
def fun(a):
    a.append(5)
    print(hex(id(a)))


a=[1,2,3]
print(hex(id(a)))
fun(a)

# Output:
# 0x7f97e1589308
# 0x7f97e1589308
```

Comment: What do you mean by "creates a local copy"?  Python doesn't create a second list and then update both whenever one changes.  Instead, both the caller and callee have a reference to the same list.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have edited a part in the answer in reference to your question. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Y is not value its just some bindings to memory. When You pass it to function its memory address is passed to function (call by reference). On the other hand x is value and when you pass it to function new local variable is created with same value. (At the assembly level all parameters of function are passed via stack pointer. Value of x and adress of y are pushed to stack pointer.